# Difference between QAS Address validation and UPS address validation

Tags: java, web

What is the difference between **QAS Address validation** and **UPS address validation**? What all validations do both support?

Comment: Hi ANU_VIN, There are loads of possible answers to this question. Would be good to hear more about what you are looking for. Are you looking for an improved checkout experience and success rate? Looking at bulk cleaning addresses? Just one country or which countries? Looking at automating shipping options?